# How do I add to a list from a form in react?

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs, forms

I am currently learning React and I am trying to make a simple list. The user can click on the "Add to the List" button, and a modal window will appear with a form where the user can input a line of text. When the form is submitted, the text input should appear in an un-ordered list. I can't seem to get the text input to appear in the un-ordered list. I am not sure what I am doing wrong. Here is my code:

```js
import React, {useState} from 'react';
import {Modal, Button, Form} from 'react-bootstrap';



function App() {

  const [newListItem, setNewListItem] = useState('');
  const [show, setShow] = useState(false);
  
  const changeOpen = () => setShow(true);
  const changeClose = () => setShow(false);
  
  var listItems = [];

 
  var addToList = (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();
    listItems.push(newListItem);
    console.log(newListItem);
  }
 
  var updateList = (e) => {
    setNewListItem(e.target.value);
    console.log(newListItem);
    e.preventDefault();
  }

  return (
    <div className="App">
      
      <h2>Simple List</h2>

      <Button onClick={changeOpen}>
        Add to the List
      </Button>


      <Modal show={show} onHide={changeClose}>
        <Modal.Header closeButton>
          <Modal.Title>This is the Title</Modal.Title>
        </Modal.Header>
              <form onSubmit={addToList}>
                <Modal.Body>               
                    <Form.Group>
                      <Form.Label>Item</Form.Label>
                      <br />
                      <Form.Control type="text" placeholder="Normal text" onChange={updateList} />
                    </Form.Group>
                </Modal.Body>
                    <Modal.Footer>
                    <Button type="sumbit">Add to List</Button>
                    </Modal.Footer>
              </form>
      </Modal>

      <ul>
        {listItems.map(item =>(
          <li>{item}</li>
        ))}
      </ul>

    </div>
  );
}

export default App;
```

The state variable 'newListItem' is being set to the text input from the form and is being added to the listItems array, but the array is not being displayed in the un-ordered list element. How can I get the array items to display?

Comment: `listItems` should be a parameter of your state, then the component will re-render when it's updated. Also, the fact that the list is unordered is irrelevant and IMO just makes the question confusing

Comment: Can you create listItems as state variable cause I think upon updation listItems array is again initialized to empty array.

Comment: Thank you for the help and clear direction.

Answer (score 1):

More no wrong method is there .Try this working code

1. use direct state variable one map function to display list
2. use [`useRef`](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-reference.html#useref) function for get the text value after form submit
3. And use **[`spread operator`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Spread_syntax)** for merge new array to old

**[Demo](https://codesandbox.io/s/proud-rgb-7swpq)**

```
function App() {
  const [newListItem, setNewListItem] = useState([]);
  const [show, setShow] = useState(false);
  const input = useRef();
  const changeOpen = () => setShow(true);
  const changeClose = () => setShow(false);

  var addToList = e => {
    e.preventDefault();
    setNewListItem([...newListItem, input.current.value]);
  };

  return (
    <div className="App">
      <h2>Simple List</h2>

      <Button onClick={changeOpen}>Add to the List</Button>

      <Modal show={show} onHide={changeClose}>
        <Modal.Header closeButton>
          <Modal.Title>This is the Title</Modal.Title>
        </Modal.Header>
        <form onSubmit={addToList}>
          <Modal.Body>
            <Form.Group>
              <Form.Label>Item</Form.Label>
              <br />
              <Form.Control type="text" ref={input} placeholder="Normal text" />
            </Form.Group>
          </Modal.Body>
          <Modal.Footer>
            <Button type="sumbit">Add to List</Button>
          </Modal.Footer>
        </form>
      </Modal>

      <ul>
        {newListItem.map((item, b) => (
          <li key={b}>{item}</li>
        ))}
      </ul>
    </div>
  );
}
```

Comment: Thank you for the help. One question though, why add three periods in front of newListItem? I can't seem to find documentation on that.

Comment: its call [spread operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Spread_syntax)